# Ajax Script No Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created an ajax script but it doesn't seem to be working. This script uses Jquery to update user firstname and lastname in mysql DB, with loading gif during update process. But the script deosn't seem to work and not even the loader is working! JQuery and Javascript that shows moodal box for name change is below,

```js
var editNameBox = document.getElementById('editName');
var editNameBtn = document.getElementById("editNameButton");
var closeEditName = document.getElementsByClassName("closeEditName")[0];
editNameBtn.onclick = function() {
  editNameBox.style.display = "block";
}
closeEditName.onclick = function() {
  editNameBox.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == editNameBox) {
    editNameBox.style.display = "none";
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(editname) {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#contentLoad").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#contentLoad").css("display", "none");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#nameChangeBtn", function() {
    var userid = $(".userid").val();
    var firstname = $("#firstNam").val();
    var secondname = $("#lastNam").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "editProfile.php";
      type: "POST";
      dataType: "json";
      data: {
        userid: userid,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname
      };
      success: function(response) {
        alert($editstatus);
      };
    });
  }));
});
```

```css
.body {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="editNameButton"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-pencil"></i></button></p>
</p>
<div id="editName" class="editname">
  <div class="editname-content">
    <div class="contentloader" id="contentLoad"><img src="loaders/ripple-loading.gif" height="100px" width="100px" alt="Loader" /><br>
      <strong>Loading... </strong></div>
    <span class="closeEditName">&times;</span>
    <p class="center"><strong>Edit Your Name</strong><br>
      <hr>
    </p>
    <br><br>
    <label><strong>First Name:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="name" placeholder="<?php echo ' '. $userData['first_name'] ?>" class="firstname" id="firstNam" /><br><br>
    <label><strong>Last Name:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="name" placeholder="<?php echo ' '. $userData['last_name'] ?> " class="secondname" id="lastNam" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Change Name" class="namechange" id="changeNameBtn" />

    <br>

  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var editNameBox = document.getElementById('editName');
var editNameBtn = document.getElementById("editNameButton");
var closeEditName = document.getElementsByClassName("closeEditName")[0];
editNameBtn.onclick = function() {
  editNameBox.style.display = "block";
}
closeEditName.onclick = function() {
  editNameBox.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == editNameBox) {
    editNameBox.style.display = "none";
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(editname) {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#contentLoad").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#contentLoad").css("display", "none");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#nameChangeBtn", function() {
    var userid = $(".userid").val();
    var firstname = $("#firstNam").val();
    var secondname = $("#lastNam").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "editProfile.php";
      type: "POST";
      dataType: "json";
      data: {
        userid: userid,
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname
      };
      success: function(response) {
        alert($editstatus);
      };
    });
  }));
});
```

The editProfile.php has following code :

```
<?php
require_once'user.php'; 
$user = new user();
if (!empty($_POST ['userid']) && !empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname'])){
$userid = $_POST ['userid'];
$firstname = $_POST ['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST ['lastname'];
$prevCon ['where'] = array('id' => $userid);
$prevCon ['return_type'] = 'single';
$prevUser = $user -> getRows($prevCon);
  if (!empty ($prevUser)){
      $conditions = array ( 'id' => $userid);
      $data = array ('first_name' => $firstname, 'last_name' => $lastname);
      $update = $user -> update ($data, $conditions);
  }
  if ($update){
      $editstatus = "Name Changed Successfully";
  } 
  else {
      $editstatus = "Failed to change your name, please try again.";
  }
}
else {
$editstatus = "First Name & Last Name fields can't be empty!";
}


echo json_encode ($editstatus);

?>
```

And lastly my html code geos like this,

```
<button id="editNameButton"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-pencil"></i></button></p>
    </p>
<div id="editName" class="editname">
  <div class="editname-content">
  <div class="contentloader" id="contentLoad"><img src="loaders/ripple-loading.gif" height = "100px" width = "100px" alt="Loader" /><br>
    <strong>Loading... </strong></div>
    <span class="closeEditName">&times;</span>
    <p class="center"><strong>Edit Your Name</strong><br><hr></p>
<br><br>
     <label><strong>First Name:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="name" placeholder="<?php echo ' '. $userData['first_name'] ?>" class="firstname" id = "firstNam" /><br><br>
    <label><strong>Last Name:</strong></label><br>
    <input type="name" placeholder="<?php echo ' '. $userData['last_name'] ?> "class="secondname" id = "lastNam" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value = "Change Name" class ="namechange" id="changeNameBtn" />

<br>

 </div>
</div>
```

Loader is hidden in css file. Nothing is happening when i use this script! Help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You have jQuery, use it: `$("#editNameButton").on("click",function() {
  $("#editName").hide();
  });`

Comment: i edited your question to show a pseudo working example.  Now when you run that, you see a BUNCH of syntax errors begin to be highlighted

Comment: Youneed comma between these `url: "editProfile.php";
      type: "POST";
      dataType: "json";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the syntax errors, migrated to use promise syntax for the ajax, used jQuery code for event handlers.

Note: I have no idea where you have `$(".userid").val()`, so I will leave resolution of that up to you.

```js
// since you have jQuery, I use that.
$("#editNameButton").on('click', function() {
  $('#editName').removeClass('hideme');
});
$(".closeEditName").on('click', function() {
  $('#editName').addClass('hideme');
});
$('#editName').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('hideme');
});
// no need for window event, covered by prior one
$(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#contentLoad").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#contentLoad").css("display", "none");
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#nameChangeBtn", function() {
    var userData = {
      userid: $(".userid").val(),
      firstname: $("#firstNam").val(),
      secondname: $("#lastNam").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "editProfile.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: userData
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        alert($editstatus);
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
  display: none;
}

.contentloader img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p> <button id="editNameButton"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-pencil"></i></button></p>
<p></p>
<div id="editName" class="editname">
  <div class="editname-content">
    <div class="contentloader" id="contentLoad"><img src="loaders/ripple-loading.gif" alt="Loader" /><br />
      <strong>Loading... </strong>
    </div>
    <span class="closeEditName">&times;</span>
    <p class="center"><strong>Edit Your Name</strong><br />
      <hr />
    </p>
    <br/><br/>
    <label><strong>First Name:</strong></label><br />
    <input type="name" placeholder="<?php echo ' '. $userData['first_name'] ?>" class="firstname" id="firstNam" /><br/><br/>
    <label><strong>Last Name:</strong></label><br/>
    <input type="name" placeholder="<?php echo ' '. $userData['last_name'] ?> " class="secondname" id="lastNam" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Change Name" class="namechange" id="changeNameBtn" />
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it somehow like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo $userData['id']; ?>"> // put this in your form to

$(".namechange").on("click", function() {
  //show loader
  $("#contentload").css("display", "block");

  // get data
  var userid = $("#userid").val();
  var firstname = $("#firstNam").val(); 
  var secondname = $("#lastNam").val();

  // make ajax call
  $.ajax ({
     url  : "editProfile.php";
     type : "POST";
     dataType : "json";
     data : {userid : userid, firstname : firstname, lastname : lastname};
     success : function (response){
        alert(response);

        // hide loader
        $("#contentload").css("display", "none");
     };
  });
)};
```

**Note:** you cant use $editstatus, this is only your php variable.. but you did it right by json_encoding and echoing it out but you get the variable as response

but if you want to have full control over the status you should json encode an array like this:

```
echo json_encode(array("status" => "success", "message" => "Name changed successfully"));
```

and so on and then check that status in your ajax success function with

```
if(response.status == "success") { 
   // do whatever
} else {
   // do whatever
}
```

Comment: I tried your method the real problem is that when i click the button it is not triggering the code. On clicking the button nothing happens!

Comment: i cant find a button with the class="nameChangeBtn".. if this: id="editNameButton" is your button then you have to change the jquery to $("#editNameButton").on ... or if its the input submit button then the class is is namechange and not nameChangeBtn

Comment: then try to make an alert("test"); directly after the onclick event and see if it fires.. also I've seen this: $(#lastNam).val (); should be $("#lastNam").val(); and this: $($userData['id']).val(); cant work as i think its php?

Comment: and the id of your loader is also not #LoadContent and instead its #contentLoad.. please go over your code and check for the right id's and classes, otherwise this cant work..

Comment: also all of your input fields are INSIDE of your contentload div, or do you just want to show/hide the IMAGE and not the whole div? if so you have to give that the id for the loader and not the div

Comment: The alert (test) is working perfectly fine but when i put alert test in this block of code it stops working. Any idea whats happening here?

Comment: You did not even fix the syntax errors, have to downvote